# Chrome extension: detect headers after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to detect the request/response headers from my browser. I'm storing these headers in temporary variables that I will use later.

I want also to reset these variables when a page in a tab is reloaded.

I think I figured out the commands thanks to the guides and other people's answers. Anyway I saw that when I want to detect the reload of a page, the reload event seems to be fired after some of the request headers of the page are retrieved again.

Here's an example of what I get immediately after I refresh the page:

[image: received headers]

Here's my code:

```
/* Listener to the page for reloading */
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function(tabId,changeInfo,tab){
    //Check changeInfo.url: check existence - if it does, then that means that the url was changed and thus not a refresh. 
    console.log(changeInfo)
    if (changeInfo.url === undefined) {
        //reset the variables for a certain tab id on its refresh
        if (changeInfo.status == 'loading') {
            console.log('Refresh happened for tab: '+ tabId)
            //global variables
            requestHeaders = {}
            responseHeaders = {}
        }
    }
});

/**
 * Stores HTTP request headers into an object with TabId and URI as key.
*/
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(req){
        var tabId = req.tabId;
        /* header memorization */
        console.log( tabId, req.url  );

    });
```

I realize these calls are asynchronous and to concatenate them I should put the call to `onBeforeSendHeaders` inside the callback of `tabs.onUpdated`, but in this case I'm losing (as in the case I reset the buffers) some of them because some of the headers seem to be received before the onUpdated event is fired.

How can I do to capture all the HTTP requests from when the page is loaded? That is, is there a way to attach the headers capturing function *before* the page starts receiving them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the `chrome.tabs` event at all. Rendering (`chrome.tabs`) is completely unrelated to fetching the resource (`chrome.webRequest`).

Every set of requests for a tab starts with loading the top-level frame. You can detect this kind of request by checking whether `req.type == 'main_frame'`.

Note that your code only works for one tab. You should probably store the data in a dictionary using the tabId as key, and delete the value of the dictionary when the [`chrome.tabs.onRemoved`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onRemoved) event is triggered.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize I could go that way! And yes, I'm currently using a dictionary structure to memorize the received headers according to the tab they are called from.